# Flatpak - error: unknown command search

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am trying to learn how to use `flatpak` on mu Pi 3. However when I type `flatpak search libreoffice`all I get is `error: unkknown command 'search'`

I've followed the following steps:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub-flatpakrepo
flatpak update
flatpak search libreoffice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'search' command was introduced in v0.10.1 (see https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/releases/tag/0.10.1)

The version in the Raspbian / Debian Stretch repo is the older 0.8.9 (see https://packages.debian.org/stretch/flatpak)

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I could not find any info at all.